# how to handle the app if the server is not available

Tags: android

hellow there. i have a app that is based on remote server. my app works perfectly if the server is running and crashes if the server is not available.i am testing the app in localhost so i want to handle it, my code for async task is below.

```
    public class UserBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public UserBackgroundTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Verifying Username and Password...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String login_url = "http://10.0.3.2/newRsNepal/Login.php";
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        String method = params[0];

        if (method.equals("login")) {
            String login_user = params[1];
            String login_password = params[2];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                 httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login_user, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login_password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InnerActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textUser.setText("");
            textUser.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check for `503 Service Unavailable` request code before fetching data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostExecute Use this code:

```
if (result.length>1) {
  Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"Your msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

or

```
    if (result.size>1) {
     Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"Your msg",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

or

```
   if (result==null) {
    }
```

Comment: i have used your concept and made some changes and finally the problem was solved..

if(result == null){
    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"Your msg",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Answer (score 0):

put below code in MainActivity file

```
//this function check internet connection
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
                      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
            }

//put your code here
if(isNetworkAvailable() == true)
{
        //internet connection available put your code here  
        new UserBackgroundTask().execute();
}
else
{
        //internet connection not available     
}
```